# Validation datacontract and datamember required

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api

I'm using the web api to build an API and when receiving the posted values and binding them to my model I get an error that seems out of place.

I have a simple model exactly as below:

```
public class Client
{
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    [JsonIgnore]
    public int ClientID { get; set; }
    [Required, StringLength(75)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public bool Active { get; set; }
}
```

When sending this model through into my post method on my controller

```
public object Post([FromBody]Client postedClient)
```

it goes through the x-www-form-urlencoded formatter but it throws:

```
Property 'Active' on type 'CreditSearch.Api.Models.Rest.Client' is invalid. Value-typed properties marked as [Required] must also be marked with [DataMember(IsRequired=true)] to be recognized as required. Consider attributing the declaring type with [DataContract] and the property with [DataMember(IsRequired=true)].
```

I also tried it send the same data in json format but I get the same result. I tried to add these attributes just to get the code working but Resharper and myself cannot find the correct reference. Even so I'd prefer not to add this superfluousness attributes that haven't been required before when validating in a plain MVC system.

1. Do I really need these attributes? They weren't required before.
2. If so what references do I need to add?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason this validation is there is because for reference-typed members, whenever the member is deserialized WebAPI can check that the member is not null. For value types, there is no null value so it's up to the formatter to check that the value is present in the request body. Unfortunately, our XML formatter doesn't support the [Required] attribute so it won't raise a model state error if the member is missing.

If you're OK with certain formatters not raising model state errors for the missing value-typed members, you can use this line to remove the validation:

```
config.Services.RemoveAll(typeof(ModelValidatorProvider), (provider) => provider is InvalidModelValidatorProvider);
```

Comment: For what it's worth, I can't promise anything but we'll likely remove this validator provider in a future version. It's given people more headache than it's worth.

Comment: ah sure that makes sense. So if I did want it to raise the error what reference am I missing to allow DataContract and DataMember?

Comment: System.Runtime.Serialization

Comment: Ah so DataContract and such like are only available in .NET 4.5, it's really confusing that the error message in Web Api would ask you to use it even when you can't. Thank you Youssef.

Comment: One thing to note (cause i fought with this for a day), it's important to remove the provider or validator before config.EnsureInitialized() is called. Otherwise route bindings get setup with the original settings.