# Validation For WebApi?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, fluentvalidation, model-validation

I am using the asp.net web api and I don't know if I am doing something wrong but I find it for some reason alot harder to use DataAnnotations for validation with WebApi vs MVC.

For instance if I want to use the Required Validator on a non string I have to use a DataContract with IsRequired what I find adds to the clutter.

I also find that if the data annotation fails to validate that I really don't get an error back(RestSharp thinks all is well).

I am wondering do people use anything other than DataAnnotations with the WebApi? I know in MVC there was that Fluent Validation for .net but not sure if that works with WebApi.

**Edit**

I am bit confused base on the link in the comments.

In the first part they have this

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    // Do something with the product (not shown).

    return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
}
else
{
    return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ModelState);
}
```

I thought  `Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ModelState);` will send all the model state errors back.

But then it goes

> Handling Validation Errors
>
> Web API does not automatically return an error to the client when
>   validation fails. It is up to the controller action to check the model
>   state and respond appropriately.

I am confused about the above line as like I said I thought CreateErrorResponse was handling that.

Comment: Sorry, if i'm wrong, but i find this link useful: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/model-validation-in-aspnet-web-api

Comment: @VladimirFrolov - Thanks that is very useful but I am a bit confused about some stuff. I will end by OP.

Comment: About handling validation errors: two ways are suggested in the tutorial. The first, as you said, is `Request.CreateErrorResponse` inside the controller. The second is to apply filter attribute to controller or use global filter. And inside the filter is similar `actionContext.Request.CreateErrorResponse`. "Web API does not automatically return an error to the client" means that in default configuration (i.e. without filter or model state check inside controller) you won't obtain validation error information.

Comment: hmm ok, it maybe a while till I have to check but I remember when using restsharp and same a binding failed in the model, I found that it would never make it in the method to get to the part to CreateErrorResponse, Would the second way solve that or is that just a different problem all together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding your problem with [DataContract(IsRequired=true)], there are some posts on SO itself describing why it was needed (security concerns) and why it's not needed anymore (buggy).
For reference: [Validation datacontract and datamember required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14079049/asp-net-web-api-validation-datacontract-and-datamember-required)

All you need to do to rely only on DataAnnotation attributes ist to remove InvalidModelValidatorProvider from the Web Api Config, like so:

`config.Services.RemoveAll(typeof(ModelValidatorProvider), (provider) => provider is InvalidModelValidatorProvider);`

Actually you are right, this line

```
return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ModelState);
```

will send your validation errors back to the client. What is meant by the excerpt you cited is that you must write this line either in controller's action body or in a validation filter.

Hope it helps.